# How do I install an extension in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, installation, google-chrome-extensions

I'm trying to install extensions in Chrome, but keep running into roadblocks.

I downloaded the beta version of Chrome, but every time I try to drag a crx file to the browser, it just brings up a "Save As" window.  When I do save, Windows says that it doesn't know which program to use to open the file.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I wound up fixing it:  Uninstalled, then reinstalled Chrome beta.  Now extension work.

Answer (score 5):

Download [Chrome 4 beta](http://www.google.com/intl/en/landing/chrome/beta/) and from the wrench icon you click extensions and then the extension menu will come up.Then scroll down and [get more extensions >>](https://chrome.google.com/extensions) link will be there.Click on that and you will have all sorts of extensions for Chrome.

Good luck searching :)

Comment: Indeed Chrome 3 doesn't support extensions, so there's no way to install them

Comment: so install Chrome 4 beta and follow this steps and you will have extensions :)

Comment: I have the Chrome beta, and I've been to the extensions page, but when I click on Install, it doesn't install.  I get the "Save As" window, as described in my original post.

Comment: Which Chrome beta? What version? I'm using the latest dev build and I'm at 4.0.288.dev1. The latest beta is about 4.0.249.0. If it's lower than that, you need to get a newer build.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, however, here are two options to try.

1) I noticed that "dragging" the item to the window caused the weird "Save As" error...however, if you open a Chrome window and choose "File" and "Open File"..and choose your downloaded extension file, it seems to activate it correctly.

2) You may also want to use the wrench/settings menu in Chrome to view your installed extensions.

Comment: Opening the crx file directly didn't work.  I still get the Save As dialog.